# How to create a driver for my application

Tags: c#, android, windows, device-driver

I build 2 application one for android and one for pc
My application is to make the camera of android mobile appear inside application of C#

but I didn't use DirecShow in my application..

it's work good ..but still I have to make the application of c# which display the camera 
appear as an option inside Skype and MSN which I think make this application like driver

any help to do that will be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can write a windows driver in c#. Maybe you should begin reading here: [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428)